# Pdns recursors avoid to forward not fqdn to root servers

Tags: powerdns, powerdns-recursor

I use a PDNS system with a recursor.
I noticed that some (maybe) not well configured docker containers forwards to the PDNS recursor some query without suffix (not fully qualified host name). The recursor fowards these queries to the root servers.

[image]

How I can avoid this?
I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Avoid pdns recursor to foward query withoud suffix
2. Configure PDNS to add a default zone-suffix and forward this query to DNS

Thanks.